# Windows MBR broken after a Windows update

Tags: windows-7, mbr, uefi, efi

My Windows 7 machine was working fine last night. When I booted it up it installed an update and then I started using it... It hadnt restarted since the install of the update so I didnt notice that anything went wrong but today I was greeted by a No operating system found screen when trying to boot into Windows. I tried reparing Windows 7 through the install disk I originally used to install and tried using the Repair your computer option and it just says:
This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc that is compatible with this version of Windows. This is when I try to boot into the install disk without UEFI. I must have installed Windows 7  in UEFI without realising it as the MBR partition is EFI. I havent been able to do bootrec.exe /rebuildIforgotwhattherestis because it throws an error that it needs to be running on a BIOS install for it to work.

Im absolutely exhausted because I have frantically tried for 7 hours trying almost every method available to try. Including the one where you copy the MBR from the disk and onto the HDD. I have tried making the EFI partition active and everything and still nothing.

Comment: If your MBR is broken then you were booting into Legacy mode.  Its not possible to have installed it in UEFI and have a MBR be broken.

Comment: Ahhh. I have tried doing some more troubleshooting and I have gotten as far as /fixmbr and /fixboot which didnt work before. Now im getting  a different error when I boot: Reboot and Select proper Boot device

Comment: You need to try those commands.  If you get an error post them.  MBR is only possible by booting in Legacy mode, it would not have EFI data, and if it did it wouldn't be used.

Comment: We have a new popup when I go to repair it by the way: http://imgur.com/WRoiApS

Comment: Whats the question?  Looks like you will be able to boot into Windows.  I should point out the MBR does not need repair without a reason, and it wasn't the update that did it, I would verify your hdd isn't failing

Comment: Still not booting into Windows. I tried bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd and it returns: The requested system device cannot be identified due to multiple indistinguishable devices potentially matching the identification criteria. I have tried taking my drive out and plugging it into a working machine through USB and I can access all my files just fine... Wonder whats up with it

Comment: I don't know what else you have done to your hdd.  The only command that should have been used was /fixmbr, you indicated you tried other things before doing that though.

Comment: Yeah true. No idea what im supposed to do from this point. All I can say is that I wish the repair wizard would actually work for once.

Comment: Heres an image of what start up repair shows: http://imgur.com/xNvwcLu

Answer (score 1):

All fixed!
This is really simple to fix actually. Download [this](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html) then burn it to cd and boot into it. Then select the hard drive you want to repair and in the bottom left press convert GTP to MBR and then press apply. This will do the bulk of the work for you, then all you need to do is repair the MBR by booting into the Windows 7 install disk and using the Repair this computer option and then using command line and typing bootrec.exe /repairmbr